# Redux Dispatch Infinite Loop

Tags: redux, react-redux, action, dispatch

I am using axios.get in my useeffect and then I am passing the data from response to the dispatcher. It retrieves data and dispatches and then I get the state to show data an console it but data shows infinite loop. Here is my useEffect, local state, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      // console.log(response.data)
      __storeUsers(response.data)
    })
    setUsers(showUsers)
    console.log(users)
  }, [__storeUsers, showUsers, users, setUsers])

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  showUsers: state.getUsers.users
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  __storeUsers: (data) => dispatch({type: types.STORE_USERS, payload: data}),
})
```

This is my reducer for users

```
import * as types from "./types";
const initialState = {
  users: []
}
const usersState = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.STORE_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default usersState
```

This is for practice purpose. i am not using actionCreators right now. After this I will move the axios call to the action creator. The data that I get from above goes in loop in console. Please help.

Also if I create action creator for this, that also goes in loop. Action creator is like below:

```
export const UserActions = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  if (response.data) {
    // console.log(response.data)
    dispatch({
      type: types.STORE_USERS,
      payload: response.data
    })
  } else {
    // console.log("no data")
  }
  return response
}
```

And then I use it like below

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  __storeUsers: () => dispatch(UserActions())
})
```

Both methods are firing loop in console.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your `useEffect` here is where the infinite loop occurs:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      // console.log(response.data)
      __storeUsers(response.data)
    })
    setUsers(showUsers)
    console.log(users)
  }, [__storeUsers, showUsers, users, setUsers])
```

The `useEffect` has been told that `users` is one of its dependencies and that it should re-run when this variable changes. The `useEffect` then changes the value of `users` via `setUsers` and it sees this update so runs again.

It looks like you're only depending on `users` for this `console.log`. Consider taking it out of the dependency list.

Comment: I removed the __storeUsers, showUsers, users, setUsers one by one from dependencies list and it still shows the loop.if i remove deny list [] altogether, still shows loop.